# Can I treat a subquery with one row and one column as a scalar?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have the following SQL (which can be [run against the Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/336425/fiddle-for-so-question-31417041), if you'd like):

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) AS "Count" 
  INTO #temp 
  FROM Posts
  
PRINT (SELECT * FROM #temp)
```

This produces an error:

> "Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed."

Now, in this case, I know that `#temp` is a table of one row and one column, and hence that `(SELECT * FROM #temp)` will produce only one value. Is there any way to persuade SQL Server to treat it as a scalar?

I am aware that I can save it off to a variable and then `PRINT` that instead:

```
DECLARE @count int = (SELECT * FROM #temp)
PRINT @count
```

But this seems like an extra step that shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this isn't possible according to the grammar.

The only way of doing it other than assigning to a variable at the same scope would be to wrap the `select` in a UDF as far
as I can see.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176047.aspx) States

> PRINT msg_str | @local_variable | string_expr
>
> msg_str Is a character string or Unicode string constant. For more
> information, see Constants (Transact-SQL).
>
> @ local_variable Is a variable of any valid character data type.
> @local_variable must be
> char, nchar, varchar, or nvarchar, or it must be able to be implicitly
> converted to those data types.
>
> string_expr Is an expression that
> returns a string. Can include concatenated literal values, functions,
> and variables. For more information, see Expressions (Transact-SQL).

So assuming that "functions" includes user defined functions and not just built in functions this would work. Otherwise you're out of luck.

And for your specific use case you are certainly out of luck as, even ignoring the ridiculousness of creating a scalar UDF for this, they can't access temp tables anyway.

Comment: but probably again a scalar function :-)

Comment: Makes sense; I guess PRINT is sort of a special language construct here.

Comment: @senshin well at least it's a step up from passing arguments to stored procedures as they don't accept any sort of expressions at all https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/352110/t-sql-use-scalar-functions-as-stored-procedure-parameters

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, nope.  Even a statement as simple as `PRINT (SELECT 1)` or `PRINT (SELECT TOP (1) 1)` fails.

My guess is that PRINT simply won't execute SQL of any kind to prevent possible injections.  It's PRINT, after all, not EXEC.  It's meant to return a string message to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Print is NOT a query method. It simply prints values. Seems you don't need a temp table for this though.

```
Declare @Count int
select @Count = COUNT(*) 
from Posts

Print @Count
```

Comment: Not that you could have known this from my question, but my actual use case involves executing dynamically-constructed SQL statements (blech, I know), so I think the temp table is actually necessary.

Comment: Dynamic sql has its place. No biggie. The real issue here is that you will be forced to use a variable for this.

Answer (score 0):

- [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx)

> **PRINT (Transact-SQL)**
>   Returns a user-defined message to the client.
>
> ```
> PRINT msg_str | @local_variable | string_expr
> ```
>
> - `msg_str`
>     Is a character string or Unicode string constant. For more information, see Constants (Transact-SQL).
> - `@local_variable`
>     Is a variable of any valid character data type. @local_variable must be char, nchar, varchar, or nvarchar, or it must be able to be implicitly converted to those data types.
> - `string_expr`
>     Is an expression that returns a string. Can include concatenated literal values, functions, and variables. For more information, see Expressions (Transact-SQL).

There isn't any kind of use of query or sub-query for that.

---

- [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190286.aspx)

> **Expressions (Transact-SQL)**
>
> ```
> { constant | scalar_function | [ table_name. ] column | variable  
>     | ( expression ) | ( scalar_subquery ) 
>     | { unary_operator } expression 
>     | expression { binary_operator } expression  
>     | ranking_windowed_function | aggregate_windowed_function
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx

`PRINT` requires a variable which can be set to a fairly large data stream but it has to be single variable.

Though it appears to be redundant if you are trying to debug using `PRINT` you must set it to a variable first. I cant think of any other way around it.